# Changing ONE div background to several images when links on page are hovered

Tags: javascript, css, hover, background-image, onhover

I have a page I am working on that has several links, but has a persistent area where a background fades into a new image when any of those links are hovered over. sort of like this script: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/thumbnail2.htm

except the only option with that script is to have those links target that large image, I need those links to go to separate places entirely.

What can I do about this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: So you want each link to change a different image target instead of all links the same image target?

Comment: You need to show us some of your coding for us to get a better idea of exactly what you are trying to achieve as well as it will tell us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You would just place this code within each of the small images and change the 'where_you_want_it_to_go' part, depending on the destination.

```
onmouseover=document.getElementById('where_you_want_it_to_go').innerHTML= '<img src="image.jpg/>';"
```

Is this what you were looking for?